# Struts 2 validation of parameters

Tags: post, parameters, struts2, get

Im wondering how to handle missing request parameters in a struts2 action :
Let's say you have an action to view a user profile.
The action will show the profile of a given user according to the userId parameter.

How do you handle the fact that this parameter may be missing (if user load directly the action from the url bar or if he plays with tamper data addon ...) ?

I see several options but I wonder if there are other options and which one is the best :

1. In each action, on prepare(), check if the expected parameters are given, if not redirect
2. In each action, on the method that process the request, check that parameters, if not then redirect

I also thought I could use validators to make sure parameters are there but it only works for a form, doesnt it ?

If you have any idea or any point of view on this question, I would love to hear it

Thanks

Comment: In such scenario interceptors will play better role identify tampering, I handled it with custom interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation operates on request parameters--it doesn't matter if it's via a form or request parameters.

As long as an action has appropriate setters, which it would in this case, the default validation works fine. Determining if the user has the rights to access the profile in question may also be handled using a custom validator, probably one that uses existing business logic to determine access rights.

All of that, however, may be wrapped up using Spring Security, and eliminate the need for writing your own interceptor and/or validator. Which solution is the most appropriate depends on your actual needs.